# Macro for run-once conditioning

Tags: c, if-statement, macros, conditional-statements

I am trying to build a macro that runs a code only once.
Very useful for example if you loop a code and want something inside to happen only once. The easy to use method:

```
static int checksum;

for( ; ; )
{
    if(checksum == 0) { checksum == 1; // ... }
}
```

But it is a bit wasteful and confusing. So I have this macros that use checking bits instead of checking true/false state of a variable:

```
#define CHECKSUM(d) static d checksum_boolean
#define CHECKSUM_IF(x) if( ~(checksum_boolean >> x) & 1) \
                    {                                               \
                        checksum_boolean |= 1 << x;
#define CHECKSUM_END }1
```

The `1` at the end is to force the user to put semi-colon at the end. In my compiler this is allowed.

---

The problem is figuring out how to do this without having the user to specify `x` (*n* bit to be checked).
So he can use this:

```
CHECKSUM(char); // 7 run-once codes can be used

for( ; ; )
{
    CHECKSUM_IF
        // code..
    CHECKSUM_END;
}
```

---

Ideas how can I achieve this?

Comment: *The 1 at the end is to force the user to put semi-colon at the end. In my compiler this is allowed.* , it seems that you don't know the `do { } while (0)` trick.

Comment: No I do, but clang compiler with C89.. putting a single `1` does the same thing.

Comment: @Malina No, it doesn't. It would accept `CHECKSUM_END + 3;`, for instance. That's the big advantage of the `do ... while (0)` trick: there cannot be anything between the `)` and the semicolon. (And it's valid in all versions of C, even C89.)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by it would accept `CHECKSUM_END +3;` In regular environments I use this trick.. but in the current working specifics.. it just works with `1`

Comment: It would expand to `{} 1 + 3;` is valid just as `{} 1;` is.

Comment: FWIW, have you considered`std::call_once`?

Comment: Take a look at implementation of `WARN_ONCE` in Linux Kernel: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/asm-generic/bug.h#L119

Comment: ehh.. I thought it wouldn't mater is it C or C++. Okay I will fix the tags then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're saying you want the macro to somehow automatically track which bit of your bitmask contains the flag for the current test.  You could do it like this:

```
#define CHECKSUM(d) static d checksum_boolean; \
    d checksum_mask
#define CHECKSUM_START do { checksum_mask = 1; } while (0)
#define CHECKSUM_IF do {                       \
    if (!(checksum_boolean & checksum_mask)) { \
        checksum_boolean |= checksum_mask;
#define CHECKSUM_END                           \
    }                                          \
    checksum_mask <<= 1;                       \
} while (0)
#define CHECKSUM_RESET(i) do { checksum_boolean &= ~((uintmax_t) 1 << (i)); } while (0)
```

Which you might use like this:

```
CHECKSUM(char); // 7 run-once codes can be used

for( ; ; )
{
    CHECKSUM_START;
    CHECKSUM_IF
        // code..
    CHECKSUM_END;
    CHECKSUM_IF
        // other code..
    CHECKSUM_END;
}
```

Note, however, that that has *severe* limitations:

- The `CHECKSUM_START` macro and all the corresponding `CHECKSUM_IF` macros must all appear in the same scope
- Control must always pass through `CHECKSUM_START` before any of the `CHECKSUM_IF` blocks
- Control must always reach the `CHECKSUM_IF` blocks in the same order.  It may only skip a `CHECKSUM_IF` block if it also skips all subsequent ones that use the same checksum bitmask.

Those constraints arise because the preprocessor cannot count.

To put it another way, barring macro redefinitions, a macro without any arguments always expands to exactly the same text.  Therefore, if you don't use a macro argument to indicate which flag bit applies in each case then that needs to be tracked at *run* time.

Comment: close enough! Thanks. Can you additionally add a macro for resetting a specific bit in order to allow one more run?

Comment: With or without an argument?  If "with" then it will be extremely limited in where it can be placed, for the same reasons already discussed in my answer.

Comment: How would that be accomplished without an argument? User has to specify which limited code has to be parsed one more time. So I guess with argument.

Comment: Added a `CHECKSUM_RESET()` macro.  The expected argument is the zero-based index of the flag to reset.  Note that its behavior is well-defined only in the event that the checksum variable's type is unsigned.  To work around that limitation you would need to have a second argument that duplicates the `d` argument to the `CHECKSUM()` macro.

Comment: So this resets all the bits? Isn't it possible to reset just one that is specific? (I just don't quite understand how this works, hopefully that I won't need to).

Comment: No, it resets a specific bit, as indicated by the argument.  As requested.